# SSRS place grouped datas in same row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is it conceivable to place the details of a group and align them on the same row.

Visual explenation :

[image]

The group detail would show itself from left to right, not from up to down.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Instead of a Tablix try using a Matrix component. And set column groups.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want your detail on your columns, remove the detail group from your rows. This is that little stack of three horizontal lines on your tablix. Once you've deleted the detail group, click a cell in your report. Select "Add Group -> Column Group -> Adjacent -> Show detail data." Then add a row group for whatever you want to group the data by.